# Loading Base 64 Image from temp File Issue

Tags: android, base64, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have an image coded as base64 String, and I want to pass it in another activity,
Due to the size limit of extra in the Intent, I have used this code to store it in a temp file

```
FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(imagefilename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            try {
                fos.write(encodedPhoto.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
```

And I have passed the *imagefilename* in another activity,

In the new Activity I have used this code to read it

```
try {
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(imagefilename);
                String strLine = null;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);

                if ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(strLine);
                }

                dataIO.close();
                fis.close();
                encodedPhoto = strLine;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

However in this way I cannot read correctly the original encoded Base64 photo...

I don't get any error however the String of the encoded image(*encodedPhoto*) read, seems corrupted

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your read method is wrong,

Try to use this code:

```
try {
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(imagefilename);
                String line = null;
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(fis));

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                fis.close();
                encodedPhoto = buffer.toString();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

In this way you can read the String content of the file without modification.